# How to show two specific data points from tabular data in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to plot a chart with only two data points from a CSV file that holds many more data points with a datetime x-Axis.

In the end the user should be able to compare two years of his choice out of the whole dataset.

From the API documentation I know that I can pick a range of data points from a CSV with startRow and endRow:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.startRow

But that would only plot one specific point, as you can see in [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrvagad7/3/).
Is there any other way to programmatically show specific points?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        polar: false,
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
        startRow: 3,
        endRow: 4,
        googleSpreadsheetKey: false,
        googleSpreadsheetWorksheet: false
    },
    series: [{
            name: 'val'
    }],
    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        opposite: true,
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            reserveSpace: true            
        }
    }],
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime',
        opposite: false
    }],
    pane: {
        background: []
    },
    responsive: {
        rules: []
    },
    legend: {
        title: ''
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: false
        }
    }
});
```

Edit:

I forgot to mention, that i only want to load the CSV once. After that the user should be able to select/update data points without reloading the data. 
For showing ranges of values dynamically, I used Axis min and max settings like this:

```
$(this).highcharts().update({
    xAxis:{
        min: Date.UTC(selectedStart,0,0),
        max: Date.UTC(selectedEnd,11,31)
    }
});
```

The whole dataset is loaded once and the chart axis gets updated on user interaction.
Now I am looking for something similar just not for a range but a comparison of two values off of the whole dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts data module provides a function called `parsed` that allows you to modify the fetched data programmatically before it's applied to the chart.

From Highcharts **API** (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parsed):

> **parsed: function**
>      A callback function to access the parsed columns, the
>   two-dimentional    input data array directly, before they are
>   interpreted into series    data and categories. Return false to stop
>   completion, or call    this.complete() to continue async.

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/parsed/

Comment: Thanks for your help, Kamil! Correct me, if I am wrong, but the parsed function would only execute once after the CSV gets loaded in, right? I need a solution where the user dynamically can compare points from the whole dataset. I edited my question to clarify. I was thinking of using `setData` but cannot make it work yet.